# Returning Memory Stream from a method

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, using, memorystream

**Wanted to know if the below scenario will cause any memory leak.**

Aspx page contains the below.

```
private void Generator(input)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = Helper.Instance.Generate(input))
    {
    }
}
```

Below method is called from the aspx page which returns memory stream.

```
MemoryStream Generate(input)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    //doing some stream manipulation here

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Remember to vote answers and accept them.

Comment: I question the necessity of disposing a MemoryStream. Do MemoryStreams leak? It's not like they're backed off by any unmanaged resources. It's just an artefact of inheriting IDisposable from Stream.

Answer (score 10):

- First point: if an exception is thrown by the code at:

  ```
  // doing some stream manipulation here
  ```

  then the MemoryStream will not be returned by `Helper.Instance.Generate`, so will not be disposed by the caller.
- Second point: `MemoryStream` doesn't use any unmanaged resources, so it isn't essential to call `Dispose`.

So in this case there will be no memory leak.

It would be arguably better to force a Dispose in `Helper.Instance.Generate` if an exception is thrown thus:

```
MemoryStream Generate(input)  
{      
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();      

    try
    {
        //doing some stream manipulation here        

        return stream;  
    }
    catch
    {
        stream.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is a general pattern for methods that construct, manipulate and return an `IDisposable` object.

Comment: you should always call Dispose if implemented - better save than sorry

Comment: @CarstenKönig, always dispose `IDisposable`objects is a good general rule, but I wouldn't be shocked by code that fails to dispose `IDisposable` objects that are known not to wrap unmanaged resources, such as `MemoryStream`, `DataTable`, `DataSet`.

Comment: well as long as "fails" means "do nothing" I usually don't care - and "fails" like "throws" I have yet to see

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid and **will not** generate a memory leak because the Dispose method is called after exiting the using block.

Is exactly the same as doing the following:

```
 private void Generator(input)
 {
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Helper.Instance.Manipulate(memoryStream);
    }
 }
```

Comment: -1 - it's not exactly the same: in the original version, no stream is returned to be disposed if the manipulation throws.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is value to consistently disposing even things like `MemoryStream`, `DataTable`, ... This makes it easier to read code and verify that it is correct. If you see a resource in a `using`-block you know right then that it is correct. No need to do mental flow tracing and simulating execution in your head.

The code can be verified to be correct immediately. Without thinking at all. I think that is nice.

That said, while I try to put even unnecessary things into `using` blocks I don't overdo it. If there is a reason not to dispose it (even developer convenience) I just don't.

Comment: just because a disposable resource is in a `using` block doesn't mean it's correct.  It's almost certainly being disposed, but not disposing of it is only one way for it to not be "correct".  Disposing too early is another potential problem.

Comment: @Servy disposing early is easily detected during testing. It is a harmless (low-cost) bug. Disposing never can go undetected and is dangerous (costly).

Comment: Disposing an object you still need to use is likely to result in your program crashing (or it would if this object actually did something when disposed) or at least not doing what it's supposed to.  No disposing when you should simply results in wasting system resources (which if your system isn't taxed is likely to have minimal consequences).  Regardless of which is worse, clearly neither is correct.  What is correct is to dispose of the object every time, but also always after you're done with it.

Comment: Of course. That is what using is made for. It is by default correct because the variable goes out of scope when disposed of and it is always disposed.; All I'm saying is: If a resource is in a using block (RAII-style) it never leaks. Being able to make such a statement is of value.

Comment: Well, first off, a `using` block doesn't guarantee disposal of the object.  There are several exceptional circumstances that result in it not being disposed.  Second, it assumes that the `IDisposable` object created never needs to outlive the local variable it is first assigned to.  This is frequently, but not always, the case.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe already provided some explanation. For objects that implement IDisposable, you can call Dispose as early as possible to reclaim the resources (managed and/or unmanaged), but you can decide not to call, as CLR still tracks them and will reclaim the resources via finalizers. Freeing resources via finalizers takes more time but prevents memory leak from occurring.

Memory leak will only happen if whoever implements the objects/classes fails to follow the design guidelines and forget to write the finalizers properly.

There are tons of articles and books mentioning the details, such as

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx

http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae